# Automatically, seamlessly block Google-suspected spam calls

Tags: calls, phone-app, call-screening, spam, sms-blocking

The Google Phone app now reports when a suspected call is spam. Right now when I receive such a call, I have the choice to block that number. But what I'd like to do is pre-emptively set it up so that any such call is automatically blocked without my intervention.

I've investigated apps like Root Call Blocker Pro, and while they seem to do the silent, transparent blocking I'm after, it seems to require me actively maintaining a black list, entering the phone numbers I want to block. I'd like to rely on the Google's suspicions to block them. How can I set this up?

Alternately, might this be something my carrier can handle on a network-level? I'd be happy to pay for a relatively cheap app or work up a tasker/etc solution, but I'd rather not pay AT&T for a monthly service.

Comment: I discovered the "suspected spam caller" feature last week (twice in one day, ugh).  Unfortunately, blocking based on that classification doesn't appear to be an option in the Phone app itself: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/phone-by-google/Md31RdUu768

Answer (score 1):

The phone app newly (as of July 13, 2018) allows a user to block calls from numbers Google suspects to be spam.

Under `Phone > Settings > Caller ID & spam`, toggle on both the `Caller ID & spam` and `Filter suspected spam calls` settings.

Reported [here](http://theverge.com/2018/7/13/17569544/google-phone-app-android-spam-call-filtering-new-feature) among other places; the article contains photos showing the steps I described above.